# How to check whether an edge is the outline of a mesh?

Tags: algorithm

I have a 3D mesh that is composed of lots of triangles. I need to only render the outline of this mesh. Please see this image http://postimage.org/image/2jnaopqro/

The way that I check whether an edge is outline is to check whether the two adjacent triangle that share this edge have different normal sign relative to current viewing direction. The view direction is defined as the vector pointing outside of the screen.

However, this method doesn't always work. As illustrated by the while arrow, you can see I do miss some of the outline. Do you know why?

Note:

```
1> I have checked that all normals are computed in CCW
2> The given mesh data is also correct. In other words, 
   no given triangle is returned with wrong order.
```

I will be very interested to know the limitation of this detection method. As I mentioned early, it works most of the time.

Thank you

Comment: It's hard to visualize from that image what's going on in 3D. It's not even clear what it's showing--is this the outline of a mesh? The mesh itself? It appears to be non-convex, in which case there can be pockets that should not be in the outline but would satisfy your sign change criterion. Are there any more constraints than "lots of triangles"?

Comment: I can't tell from the diagram, that edge you're pointing to seems to be part of only one triangle, not two?

Comment: The nearest light-brown edge pointed by two white arrows are the idea outline of this mesh. However, the dedicated method doesn't find that edge at all. BTW, the mesh is in color light-brown while detected outline is in color of light-blue. -- thank you

Comment: If you're rendering this in DirectX / OpenGL you could check whether something is on an edge or not by differences in the depth buffer values surrounding each pixel. This won't be perfect but it should work.

Comment: An edge is on the outline of a mesh if, when a viewpoint known to be outside the mesh is rotated such that its normal vector is equal and opposite the edge's, a ray is drawn along the viewpoint's normal vector and the edge in question is the first intersected edge.                  Basically, if you rotate your viewpoint to face the edge, then draw an intersecting vector towards the edge, and the edge you're testing is the first intersected edge, it's on the outline. Inefficient probably, but sound.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do "toon shading," this is often done not by finding the actual edge, but by (for example)  filling with white, drawing the mesh as solid black outlined triangles (possibly padded bit), then drawing the mesh as non-outlined white triangles in front of it. The result is a black outline of the mesh.

Comment: I don't see the relationship between this answer and my question

Comment: Sorry. If it's really the mathematical edges that make up the visual outline you're after, and not just a way of *drawing* that outline, then my answer doesn't help at all. But this is a technique that's often used to draw the outline of a mesh when doing toon shading.